# Obtener el nombre de una imagen binaria con base64 al descargarla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente imagen base64:

```
<img alt="imagen de prueba" width="16" height="16" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAA……… />
```

Cuando ejecuto la vista en el navegador y muestro la imagen, al momento de descargarla, al colocar guardar imagen como… en nombre, me aparece con el nombre de “descarga.png”. Me gustaría saber cómo colocarle el nombre verdadero o uno que desee al archivo para descargar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

El formato de [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) no permite especificar un nombre para el archivo pero tienes otras alternativas.

Podrías agregar un link de descarga, poner el nombre en el atributo `download` y la data otra vez en el atributo `href`

```
<a download="Nombre de prueba.png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOwSUgAB...">Descargar</a>
```

Comment: Si controlas las imágenes y todo, también podrías poner el nombre en un etiqueta de [XMP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMP) en la imagen PNG.  Pero no hay estándares para hacer eso, solo depende en tu convención.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar el botón `download` si te sirve, quedando de esta manera:

```
 <a href="/images/nombredelaimagen.png" download="nombredelaimagen">Nombre de la imagen </a>
```

Aclaro que este botón no funciona en navegadores Safari.